# put Crawled data and mysql data together in Solr

Tags: php, mysql, solr, nutch, dataimporthandler

i am using `

> Nutch

` and '

> Solr

integration process. i am able to crawl some website data and pass it into solr system,which i am able to access easily.Now i want to import data from mysql also and put both data together but different index. i already tried to import data from mysql and i was also successful in doing that but then it replaced all the indexes created on crawled data , indirectly i lost mine crawled data. so can anyone help me out for doing the above process?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to create a separate collection for the import task from MySQL. These are defined in your Solr configuration directory - see `example/solr` in the distribution for a minimal setup. You can create as many collections as you need, and each collection will be handled separately from existing collections.

There's also the possibility of having different content in the same index, but that might cause an issue with Nutch - it will require you to change `preImportDeleteQuery` in the DataImportHandler, and handle deletes from the data set by yourself.